# How to create grid to have 5 columns and small screen 2 columns in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create `Grid` using material UI + reactJs.

I am following this url https://mui.com/system/react-grid/.

But here there is problem we can't able to create **5** columns in grid. So I try to create custom grid which has 5 columns for large screen. For medium screen, I need 3 columns, and for mobile 2 columns.

I am able to create 5 column but issue is mobile I am not able to create 2 column layout.

Current output:

```
1 2
3 4
5
11 22
33 44
```

Expected output

```
1  2
3  4
5  11
22 33
44
```

Here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-joliot-3xc7bo?file=/src/App.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  /* the components you used */
  Typography
} from "@mui/material";
import { styled } from "@mui/material";

export const DGrid = styled("div")({
  display: "flex",
  alignItems: "flexStart",
  flexWrap: "wrap"
});

export const DGridCol = styled("div")({
  width: "calc(100% / 5 - 16px)",
  marginBottom: "24px",
  marginRight: "20px",
  "&:last-child": { marginRight: "0px" },
  "@media (max-width: 768px)": {
    width: "calc(100% / 2 - 8px)",
    marginBottom: "15px",
    marginRight: "16px",
    "&:last-child": { marginRight: 16 },
    "&:nth-child(2),&:nth-child(4),&:nth-child(6)": { marginRight: 0 }
  }
});

/**
 * how you used the components
 */
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <DGrid>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "red" }}>1</div>
        </DGridCol>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "yellow" }}>2</div>
        </DGridCol>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "red" }}>3</div>
        </DGridCol>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "yellow" }}>4</div>
        </DGridCol>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "red" }}>5</div>
        </DGridCol>
      </DGrid>

      <DGrid>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "red" }}>11</div>
        </DGridCol>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "yellow" }}>22</div>
        </DGridCol>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "red" }}>33</div>
        </DGridCol>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "yellow" }}>44</div>
        </DGridCol>
      </DGrid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should wrap all items inside one `DGrid` because each grid displays in blocks.

```js
   <DGrid>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "red" }}>1</div>
        </DGridCol>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "yellow" }}>2</div>
        </DGridCol>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "red" }}>3</div>
        </DGridCol>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "yellow" }}>4</div>
        </DGridCol>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "red" }}>5</div>
        </DGridCol>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "red" }}>11</div>
        </DGridCol>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "yellow" }}>22</div>
        </DGridCol>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "red" }}>33</div>
        </DGridCol>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "yellow" }}>44</div>
        </DGridCol>
      </DGrid>
```

Then just modify one property css to allow all pair items with marginRight 0 inside `DGridCol`. This will do that each pair item has marginRight 0 and float with the previous col

```css
export const DGridCol = styled("div")({
  …
  "@media (max-width: 768px)": {
    …
    "&:nth-child(n+1)": { marginRight: 0 }
    …
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a grid layout then why not use a grid layout? Instead of `display: "flex"` use `display: "grid"` and define the columns you want to use. I suggest sticking to "mobile first" design. This means you define the CSS for the mobile view and use media queries to progressively override CSS rules as the screen size gets larger.

Example:

```
export const DGrid = styled("div")({
  display: "grid",
  columnGap: "20px",
  rowGap: "24px",
  gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(2, 1fr)",   // <-- 2 column mobile
  "@media (min-width: 768px)": {
    gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(3, 1fr)", // <-- 3 column "medium" *
  },
  "@media (min-width: 1280px)": {
    gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(5, 1fr)", // <-- 5 column "large" *
  },
});

export const DGridCol = styled("div")({});
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

**** Note:** Tweak the breakpoint values to suit your app's specific needs.*

[image: Edit how-to-create-grid-have-5-coloumn-and-small-screen-2-coloumn-in-reactjs]

Full code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { styled } from "@mui/material";

export const DGrid = styled("div")({
  display: "grid",
  columnGap: "20px",
  rowGap: "24px",
  gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(2, 1fr)",
  "@media (min-width: 768px)": {
    gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(3, 1fr)"
  },
  "@media (min-width: 1280px)": {
    gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(5, 1fr)"
  }
});

export const DGridCol = styled("div")({});

/**
 * how you used the components
 */
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <DGrid>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "red" }}>1</div>
        </DGridCol>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "yellow" }}>2</div>
        </DGridCol>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "red" }}>3</div>
        </DGridCol>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "yellow" }}>4</div>
        </DGridCol>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "red" }}>5</div>
        </DGridCol>
      </DGrid>
      <br />
      <DGrid>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "red" }}>11</div>
        </DGridCol>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "yellow" }}>22</div>
        </DGridCol>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "red" }}>33</div>
        </DGridCol>
        <DGridCol>
          <div style={{ background: "yellow" }}>44</div>
        </DGridCol>
      </DGrid>
    </div>
  );
}
```